# Cannot convert fetched data from api to json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

so, I was trying to make a weather app that gives the temperature of the city entered,
it was always running the code in the catch. And when tried to debug it the output of the response was getting printed but not of data. I am a beginner so please ignore my mistakes and improper code discipline,
hope u can help me to fix this issue :)!

```js
const submit = document.getElementById("btnsubmit");
const cityname = document.getElementById("cityname");
const city_output = document.getElementById("cityoutput");
const temp_status = document.getElementById('temp_status');
const temp = document.getElementById('temp');

const getInfo = async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const cityval = cityname.value;
  if (cityval === '') {
    city_output.innerText = `please write a value`;
  } else {
    try {
      let url = `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityval}&units=metric&appid=(myapiid)`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      // console.log(response);
      const data = await response.json();
      // console.log(data);
      const arrData = [data];
      // console.log(arrData);
      temp.innerText = arrData[0].main.temp;
      temp_status.innerText = arrData[0].weather[0].main;
    } catch {
      city_output.innerText = `please write city name properly`;

    }
  }
};
submit.addEventListener('click', getInfo);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="main">
        <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label " class="form-label">Eneter City Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cityname" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
             
            </div>
          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsubmit" >Submit</button>
          </form>

<div id="cityoutput">
cityname  
</div>
<div id="temp_status">cloudy</div>

<div id="temp">0 &deg; C</div>


    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 75.8333,
    "lat": 22.7179
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 801,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "few clouds",
    "icon": "02d"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 30.1,
    "feels_like": 33.44,
    "temp_min": 30.1,
    "temp_max": 30.1,
    "pressure": 1000,
    "humidity": 62
  },
  "visibility": 6000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.14,
    "deg": 140
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 20
  },
  "dt": 1626090800,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 9067,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1626049154,
    "sunset": 1626097494
  },
  "timezone": 19800,
  "id": 1269743,
  "name": "Indore",
  "cod": 200
} {
  "mode": "full",
  "isActive": false
}
```

Comment: Could you at least try to format your code/JSON so it's readable?

Comment: I think you could print the error stacktrace to the console in the `catch` clause, it might help you (and us) a lot

Comment: Have you set a proper appid parameter, when you do the fetch operation? Otherwise you might run into a cors situation. You should definitely do `catch(e) { console.error(e); } in your code, and not ignore the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it should work properly. The only thing I found in your sample data is a missing comma at 3rd last line

```html
  "cod": 200
}, {
  "mode": "full",
  "isActive": false
}
```

Here is the link for plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/tkMpa6a17opXEwZX?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: that data is directly coming from API,I just copy-pasted it, I don't know what is wrong , innertext is not getting changed and data is not fetched.Thanks <3